# django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a Django application which works fine for sometime after every deployment but after some time I get this error,

```
[Wed Sep 09 14:05:54.904121 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5256] [remote 10.0.2.132:60756] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Sep 09 14:05:54.904124 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5256] [remote 10.0.2.132:60756]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 843, in _resolve_lookup
[Wed Sep 09 14:05:54.904127 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5256] [remote 10.0.2.132:60756]     current = current[int(bit)]
[Wed Sep 09 14:05:54.904129 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5256] [remote 10.0.2.132:60756] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'exception_type'
[Wed Sep 09 14:05:54.904132 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5256] [remote 10.0.2.132:60756]
[Wed Sep 09 14:05:54.904135 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5256] [remote 10.0.2.132:60756] During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[Wed Sep 09 14:05:54.904137 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5256] [remote 10.0.2.132:60756] 
[Wed Sep 09 14:05:54.904143 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5256] [remote 10.0.2.132:60756]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 850, in _resolve_lookup
[Wed Sep 09 14:05:54.904146 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5256] [remote 10.0.2.132:60756]     (bit, current))  # missing attribute
[Wed Sep 09 14:05:54.904163 2020] [wsgi:error] [pid 5256] [remote 10.0.2.132:60756] django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [exception_type] in [{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {'is_email': True, 'unicode_hint': '', 'frames': [], 'request': <WSGIRequest: POST '/api/jsonws/invoke'>, 'user_str': '[unable to retrieve the current user]', '...
```

and users are unable to login. It's an API only application. I am using `djangorestframework==3.10.3` and `Django==2.2.7`. Please suggest the solution to this issue.

Comment: Is there a traceback?

Comment: @theEpsilon stack trace added.

Comment: django is looking for `[exception_type]`. maybe remove the key from the list it is inside of?

Comment: @HarryMoreno can you please explain a bit?

Comment: django is looking for a key named `exception_type` inside of `[{'True': True, 'False': False, 'None': None}, {'is_email': True, 'unicode_hint': '', 'frames': [], 'request': <WSGIRequest: POST '/api/jsonws/invoke'>, 'user_str': '[unable to retrieve the current user]', '...` please share your code to get more help.